# how to use sinch to call app-to-phone?

Tags: ios, sinch

i am trying to use sinch iOS SDK to make an app-to-phone call.
when I get `clientDidStart` I make a call to `sinchCallClient.callPhoneNumber("+46000000000")` (calling the test number provided by sinch) but I never get to the `callDidEstablish` or any of the error callbacks either (keep waiting for function call to end).
I see these log messages:

`(audio_device_generic.cc:66): BuiltInAGCIsAvailable: Not supported on this platform`
(area - webrtc.
severity - Warn.)

`Use of audio session mode is disabled.`
(area - audiosession.
severity - Trace.)

from the sinch documentation it seems i'm not supposed to manage AVAudioSession, it's taken care of by the SDK.

am i missing something?  what do i need to do for the call to be established?

i'll mention also that i'm writing in Swift and i'm pretty new to iOS development.

Answer (score 0):

turns out I was actually setting the call delegate in the wrong place.  thanks anyway!